# How to know which remote repository a dependency came from?

Tags: android, gradle

In a large android project, I want to analyze all dependencies and know each one from which repo came from so I can use the [new gradle feature](https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/release-notes.html#repository-to-dependency-matching)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can try using `./gradlew app:dependencies` to see a whole dependency tree.